# Dynamically changing the column header text in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a table with 3 columns which have the following values in the headers: 'No.', 'X [mm]', 'Y [mm]'. This table contain the coordinates of points in millimeters. I have a checkbox on checking of which the table should repopulate to show the coordinates in inches. Moreover, the column header values should be: 'No.', 'X [in]', 'Y [in]'.

In short I want to dynamically change the header text of the table.

In detail:
The table is a subclass of JTable. Moreover, a subclass of 'DefaultTableModel' has been set as the model for the table. I have provided the header values in the constructer of the datamodel subclass.

Any idea? My application is compatible with only jdk v1.4 so it would be good if the solution is compatible with the verion :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can update the TableColumnModel directly:

```
JTableHeader th = table.getTableHeader();
TableColumnModel tcm = th.getColumnModel();
TableColumn tc = tcm.getColumn(0);
tc.setHeaderValue( "???" );
th.repaint();
```

Comment: This is not a 100% solution cause it works only until model is changed or "tableStructureChanged" is fired. Then column text will be re-read from the model.

Comment: If that is an issue you can use table.setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel( false ) after the table is initially created

Comment: Anyone else getting a memory leak when doing this?  If I tab through table for a long time, my heap grows and grows and grows.

Comment: how to fire tableStructure ya @EugeneRyzhikov...?
Is setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel(false) need to be called before setHeaderValue() as @camickr said?

Answer (score 11):

If you have column number use that code

```
 jtable.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setHeaderValue("newHeader");
```

Comment: You need to call `jtable.getTableHeader().repaint();` after the code to update the table.

Answer (score 3):

I can't test here but familiar that this method '`[DefaultTableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(...)][1]`' should do what you want.

Basically, you run '`DefaultTableModel.getColumnCount()`' to find out how many column (unless you already know). Then you run '`DefaultTableModel.getColumnName(int ColumnIndex)`' to get the name of each, change it the way you want and put it in an array. After thatn, you set them back using '`DefaultTableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(...)`'.

Hope this helps.